# "primaryColor" property in "ThemeData" does not work in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm currently investigating how to use ThemeData in the Flutter application.
It should work with the code below, but the color theme doesn't apply as expected.

Curiously, using the "primarySwatch" option instead of the "primaryColor" option applies the theme as expected.

The execution environment is `Chrome` on `Windows10`. Neither has a dark theme applied.
In addition, the results were the same in the `Android11` environment of the real machine and the virtual environment.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(primaryColor: Colors.purple), // This "primaryColor" option does not working.
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Test App'),
        ),
        body: Container(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Below is my flutter environments.

```
Flutter 2.5.1 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision ffb2ecea52 (5 days ago) • 2021-09-17 15:26:33 -0400
Engine • revision b3af521a05
Tools • Dart 2.14.2
```

What did I make a mistake in the code?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

With the newest versions of Flutter, it's correct that `primaryColor` and `accentColor` inside `ThemeData` do not work. Instead, you should use the new `colorScheme` property of the `ThemeData`.

```dart
ThemeData(colorScheme: ColorScheme(
  primary: Colors.blue,
  primaryVariant: Colors.red,
  secondary: Colors.green,
  // all fields should have a value
));
```

See [the reference here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ColorScheme-class.html).

To know what values to pick for the variants etc., take a look at the [Material design specification](https://material.io/design/color/the-color-system.html#color-theme-creation).

Comment: Thank you for answering.
As you pointed out, when I specified the theme with the `colorScheme` property instead of the `primaryColor` property, I was able to change the color of the theme of the app.

Comment: How do you add font to this ThemeData?

Comment: For that you should still be able to use `fontFamily` directly inside `ThemeData`. The `ColorScheme` is only for the colors (as the name suggests :p)

Answer (score 1):

use

```
theme: ThemeData(
      colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSwatch(primarySwatch: Colors.amber),
  )
```

Comment: It would be nice to give a brief explanation of how this works / how it solves the problem, and how it's different than existing answers.

Answer (score 0):

the best way to set the theme to make it sperate file of theme and call in main file and the primary color is working for me `theme: ThemeData()`, like that you can also set theme of your icon and also you can set theme of your text.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    ThemeData appthemedata(BuildContext context)
    {
      return ThemeData(
        primaryColor:appcolor,
        // scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.white,
        appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
            centerTitle: true,
            elevation: 0,
            textTheme: TextTheme(headline1: AppBarTextStyle )
        ),
        textTheme: TextTheme(
    
          headline1: TitleTextStyle,
          bodyText1:Body1TextStyle,
        ),
        iconTheme: IconThemeData(
          color:Colors.white,
          size: 17,
        ),
      );
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. But when I tried that method, the theme color didn't change.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think everything is deprecated like :

```
scaffoldBackgroundColor: Color(0x0FF0A0E21),    // just an example 
// works perfectly.
```

This color is applied to the body part.

Answer (score 0):

```
MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: Color(0xFF090C22), // for scaffold background
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.light().copyWith( // to use the primaryColor
          primary: Colors.red,
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Still not working but I used appBarTheme to change the appbar color

```
return MaterialApp(
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
  theme: ThemeData(
  //primaryColor: const Color(0xFF0A0E21),// not working
    scaffoldBackgroundColor: Color(0xFF0A0E21),
   appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
    backgroundColor: Color(0xFF0A0E21),),
    textTheme: const TextTheme(
  bodyText2: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)

    ),
  ),
```